# How to optionally pass in values to a closure in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, syntax

I have the following function which reads some heart rate data and accepts a callback in the form of a closure, as such:

```
func readHeartRate(callback: ((samples: [HKQuantitySample]?, average: Double?, error: NSError!) -> Void)!){
   // ...
   // ERROR - call the callback with no samples or average
   callback(samples: nil, average: nil, error: error)
})
```

Right now, I'm explicitly passing back `nil` for `samples` and `average` to the callback.

However, since `samples` and `error` are optional, and since I declared the names in the closure explicitly, I thought this would be possible, instead:

```
callback(error: error)
```

However, when I do this xcode complains and throws the error:

```
Missing argument for parameter 'samples' in call
```

Is there a way to call the callback with only the values necessary to avoid cluttering my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a regular method, you can provide a default value for a parameter:

```
func myCallback(#error: NSError!, samples: [HKQuantitySample]? = nil, average: Double? = nil) {
}

myCallback(error: nil)
```

These parameters with default values should be at the end of the argument list.

This doesn't work in your case, since you're not defining a method; you're just specifying the method signature that callers need to pass in for the callback. You can say "pass in a method that takes an `Int`", for example, but there's no way currently to say "pass in a method that takes an `Int` **and** uses a default of 0 if I don't pass anything in".

Remember, optional values just mean the existence of a value is optional and the thing can be nil.

Comment: "These parameters with default values should be at the end of the argument list." - this holds only for unnamed params, i.e. if you have named params, any one of them can have default value.

Comment: It's more for consistency to keep argument order the same. "Place parameters with default values at the end of a function’s parameter list. This ensures that all calls to the function use the same order for their non-default arguments, and makes it clear that the same function is being called in each case." – [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)

Comment: You are right, my bad. I took it for imperative instead of recommendation, but 'should' expresses the meaning properly.

Answer (score 4):

From [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

> Closure expression syntax can use constant parameters, variable parameters, and inout parameters. **Default values cannot be provided.** Variadic parameters can be used if you name the variadic parameter and place it last in the parameter list.

So only way to be able to call closure with variable number of specified parameters is by using variadic params, which - I assume - is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have had occasions where I decided to wrap a closure in a function so that I could provide a default parameter. It works like this:

```
let myClosure: String -> () = { string in
    println(string)
}

func myFunc(string: String = "default") {
    myClosure(string)
}

myFunc()       // prints "default"
```

I know that your goal is to "declutter" your code, so whether or not writing wrapper functions is what you want, I don't know, but it works.